# How to set a job token in declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

There is possible to set a token in job properties in jenkins web interface, but i didn't find it in pipeline documentation.
I talking about that one:
[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin) is a solution.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  triggers {
    GenericTrigger(
     genericVariables: [
      [key: 'ref', value: '$.ref']
     ],

     causeString: 'Triggered on $ref',

     token: 'abc123',

     printContributedVariables: true,
     printPostContent: true,

     silentResponse: false,

     regexpFilterText: '$ref',
     regexpFilterExpression: 'refs/heads/' + BRANCH_NAME
    )
  }
  stages {
    stage('Some step') {
      steps {
        sh "echo $ref"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It can be triggered with something like:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "headerWithNumber: nbr123" -H "headerWithString: a b c" -d '{ "before": "1848f12", "after": "5cab1", "ref": "refs/heads/develop" }' -vs http://admin:admin@localhost:8080/jenkins/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?requestWithNumber=nbr%20123\&requestWithString=a%20string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the generic webhook trigger plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
job('example') {
    authenticationToken('secret')
}
```

Documentation can be found here: https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.FreeStyleJob.authenticationToken

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers .

Right now pipeline syntax supports 3 triggers - cron, pollSCM and upstream.

**But** you should be able to set the token trigger in the jenkins configuration interface and it should work.